# LDAP query to get the list of users which are matching the group pattern

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to query the groups from Ldap starting with `groupname-*` and all users part of these groups.

Group filter condition is: `(CN=groupname-*)`.

User filter condition is: `(memberof=cn=groupname*,OU=Application,OU=Groupings,DC=xx,DC=com))`

This is returning all groups matching the pattern. However I'm not able to get the users details.Works only when I specify the complete group name in user filter. Is there any way to get all users matching the group pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are querying AD. When searching for `memberOf`, only complete values are supported, not wildcards.

So your best bet is to query the groups and read their `member` attribute in order to get a list of user DNs.